# I am attempting to deploy a django project on an Ubuntu server but I keep getting a "Connection timed out" error

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I set the project up with a viturualhost and I have configured the apache server accordingly as far as I understand. I initially tested the server out with a basic django skeleton project which ran perfectly fine, both on the django server on port :8000 and also on the apache server with just the plain domain address. After uploading the project I configured and migrated the database and installed all requirements. I am able to use the "python manage.py runserver" command with no visible errors. Also the apache error log does not display any serious errors that could possibly be causing the problem. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: That's not an image of code, it's a view of the configurations.. I didn't say there was necessarily anything wrong with them in particular, it's just to make a point that the project is configured as per requirements. Similar to someone asking for a view of error logs.. What am I supposed to show if there aren't any noticeable errors in the project?

Comment: It's still images of text, which are hard to read and impossible to search. Whether you're posting code or configuration files, post them as text.

Comment: Ohk, I understand.. Thanks for the pointer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the firewall (ufw). All I had to do was deactivate the firewall `$ sudo ufw disable`   or give apache permission to query/make requests to the server. Instructions on configuring the firewall can be found [here](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-ufw-firewall-on-ubuntu-and-debian/).